# Bash/shell script: bash syntax error in expression with URL

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that will get a list of URLs, and it will use bash `for` to delete these URLs.

List of URLs:

```sh
 [root@ov]# openstack secret list -l 100 | awk -F "|" '{print $2}' | grep htt
 http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/0948091a-aa4c-4b32-988f-8a70284abe66
 http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/0bc37721-b4b4-4a2c-9e61-299bb9dd47b7
 http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/0d16ac37-a9b2-4950-8615-21d0322fb0cc
 http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/706e5c7c-db0e-47b0-8b1c-ff5872a0f0cc
 http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/73e6dad4-c61f-45f1-9112-ca56bdeb1a39
 http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/7435473d-5731-4797-9917-476461a8e301
 http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/78ba680c-9c09-4e60-a515-e4f9ec9246d6
 http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/78c0f5eb-8527-43cf-9e5c-c7d32fa098cb
 http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/83470fd2-5f3d-4f75-80e9-80fa02a91ab1
 http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/84d15215-2719-4720-bccf-deb6543ca08a
 http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/87ae179e-a847-46af-be1f-41c8559c55f5
```

The script is shown below:

```sh
[root@ov]# secrets=($(openstack secret list -l 100 | awk -F "|" '{print $2}' | grep HTTP))

[root@ov]# for i in ${secrets[@]}; do echo ${secret[i]}; done
-bash: http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/0948091a-aa4c-4b32-988f-8a70284abe66: syntax error in expression (error token is "://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/0948091a-aa4c-4b32-988f-8a70284abe66")

[root@ov]# for i in ${secrets[@]}; do echo "${secret[i]}"; done
-bash: http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/0948091a-aa4c-4b32-988f-8a70284abe66: syntax error in expression (error token is "://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/0948091a-aa4c-4b32-988f-8a70284abe66")
```

as you can see, I also get this error:

`-bash: http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/0948091a-aa4c-4b32-988f-8a70284abe66: syntax error in expression (error token is "://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/0948091a-aa4c-4b32-988f-8a70284abe66")`

I am search a lot online, but everyone has different syntax error in expression.

I could `echo http://10.250.23.52:9311/v1/secrets/0948091a-aa4c-4b32-988f-8a70284abe66` but I can not do`echo ${secret[i]}`. why is it?

Please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Quoting should do the trick: `echo "${secret[i]}"`

Comment: @EugenRieck I thought so, but as you can see in my update, it still does not work. I am so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is the URL, so just echo that:

```
for i in ${secrets[@]}; do echo $i; done
```

Quotes don't make a difference in this case, but are preferred:

```
for i in "${secrets[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

You're getting your error because you're trying to use the URL as a numeric expression for the array index, and URLs are not valid numerical expressions.

Comment: Thank you. indeed, I use the wrong syntax.

I should use the for loop in either of two ways:
`for i in ${!secrets[@]}; do echo "index is $i, secret is ${secrets[$i]}"; done`

`for i in ${secrets[@]}; do echo $i; done`